# SOAP request serialization in Mono

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, mono

I want to use WCF service in my client application. There is no problems if I run my app in .NET, but when I run it in Mono I have a problem with my SOAP message. When I checked my requests (created in Mono and .NET) in Fiddler I could see some differences.

**.NET request**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <ActivityId CorrelationId="cf76ec82-9a16-4c0f-840c-0a2f2afc0c39" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">2d22e7a7-56a6-4972-836c-56c6fcda0a35</ActivityId>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <login xmlns="http://xml.kamsoft.pl/ws/kaas/login_types">
            <credentials>
                <item>
                    <name>login</name>
                    <value>
                        <stringValue>login</stringValue>
                    </value>
                </item>
            </credentials>
            <password>password</password>
        </login>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**Mono request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        < xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <login>
                <credentials xmlns="http://xml.kamsoft.pl/ws/kaas/login_types">
                    <item>
                        <name>login</name>
                        <value>
                            <stringValue>login</stringValue>
                        </value>
                    </item>
                </credentials>
                <password xmlns="http://xml.kamsoft.pl/ws/kaas/login_types">password</password>
            </login/>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Is there any solution or workaround to fix this issue?
There is an issue reported on Mono's bugzilla with the same problem: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6677 without any answer.

This problem can be reproduced by generating service reference (without asynchronous operations) in Visual Studio 2013 from webservice from address: https://ewus.nfz.gov.pl/ws-broker-server-ewus-auth-test/services/Auth?wsdl and using this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ewusAuthService = new AuthClient();
    var loginRequest = new loginRequest();
    var credentials = new List<loginParam>
                          {
                              new loginParam
                                  {
                                      name = "login",
                                      value = new paramValue { Item = "login" },
                                  },
                          };
    loginRequest.credentials = credentials.ToArray();
    loginRequest.password = "password";

    string loginReturn;
    authToken authToken;
    session result = ewusAuthService.login(loginRequest, out authToken, out loginReturn);
    Console.WriteLine(result.id);
}
```